# Turning a game into a server-client game

Tags: c#, unity, client-server

I'm redoing a game i wrote in XNA to Unity. The XNA game was the client to a server I wrote as a console application.

How does Unity work with a server exactly, and how do you set that up?

Comment: Short/weak answer is to use Unity's new(ish) UNet http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNet.html functionality. You can build headless servers (for Linux at least, not sure elsewise), so you should be able to duplicate the setup you had in XNA. I don't currently have experience doing this, so only responding in comment. :) Sorry I can't offer more information!

Comment: Thanks dude. Currently, I'm learning UDP, so I've downloaded a client-server based chat, and I'm turning the server of the chat to a server for my game, and I have a component that interacts with the server on unity...